# Password Reset issue with Django 2.2.5

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, reset-password

I am trying to figure out an issue I'm having with what happens after submitting the password reset form supplied by django.contrib.auth.urls. When hitting the button to request the submit button an email is sent properly to the email associated with the user account, but a 505 error page is displayed. In looking at the error log the error given is:

> Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

In `myproject/urls.py` I have the following line as part of the urlspattern:

```
path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace = 'accounts'))
```

In `accounts/urls.py` I have the following lines as part of the urlspattern:

```
path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

I think the issue is with Django attempting to use the equivalent of `url 'password_reset_done'` instead of `url 'accounts:password_reset_done'`.

Any help in tracking this down would be appreciated.

Comment: 505? Version not supported? Show us the full error traceback!

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure out the issue. I was getting an error because in the `urls.py` file in my accounts app I had the line:

> app_name='accounts'

It looks like the default routing for the password_reset_done page is the equivalent of `url 'password_reset_done'`. Since the above line was in the accounts url.py file the default path would require the equivalent of `url 'accounts:password_reset_done'` . By removing the app_name line from the urls.py file I was able to solve the problem.